# How to set my eslint config according to the already existing eslint config of my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I want to enable auto linting on save in my code. But when i do changes to the existing files of codebase, due to auto linting it shows too many changes like space and "". How do i enable auto linting according to existing configuration of eslint of my codebase?

Comment: Have you tried to set `"fix": true`?

Comment: please tell us ide u are using, there it has configurations for lint what config u want use.

Comment: I am using vscode.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.